# How do I lock a cell reference in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a large amount of data that reference cells. I want to lock these references without going into each cell to change the equation. I know there is a way to do a script in excel. I don't know if there is a way to create the same type of script in excel.

Those interested in the excel script:

```
Sub test()

Dim c As Range

For Each c In Selection

    c.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(c.Formula, xlA1, , xlAbsolute) 

Next 

End Sub
```

Thanks Guys!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no Spreadsheet Service method that is equivalent to VBA's `Application.ConvertFormula()`.

You could enter a feature request on the [Google Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues). If you do, add a comment here to let us know the issue number.